# métodos Com retorno Python

Tags: python, método, atributos

estou comecando em Python e tem um erro que nao estou conseguindo resolver.
tenhoesses dois codigos:

Conta.py

```
class Conta:
def __init__(Self, numero, cpf, nomeTitular, saldo):
    Self.numero = numero
    Self.cpf = cpf
    Self.nomeTitular = nomeTitular
    Self.saldo = saldo

def depositar(self, valor):
    self.valor += valor

def sacar(self, valor):
    self.saldo -= valor

def gerarExtrato(self):
    print(f"Numero{self.numero} \n Cpf: {self.cpf} \n Saldo: {self.saldo}")

def sacar(self,valor):
    if self.saldo < valor:
        return False
    else:
        self.saldo -= valor
        return True
```

ClassA.py

```
from Conta import Conta

conta1 = Conta(1, 123, "Joao", 0)
conta2 = Conta(3, 456, "Maria", 0)

conta2.gerarExtrato()
```

quando executo o "ClassA.py" eu esperava receber os dados de gerarExtrato(), porem acontece esse erro:
C:/Users/Daniel/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/programacao/Faculdade/PYTHON/PythonOO/Tema2/ClassA.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\programacao\Faculdade\PYTHON\PythonOO\Tema2\ClassA.py", line 6, in 
conta2.gerarExtrato()
AttributeError: 'Conta' object has no attribute 'gerarExtrato'
PS C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\programacao>

qual foi o meu erro ?

Grato!

Comment: Não há erros no seu código, verifique se o arquivo foi escrito corretamente, respeitando os espaços e tabs.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O código está correto. Só certifique-se que os métodos da classe Conta estejam identados no escopo da classe.

```
class Conta:
    def __init__(Self, numero, cpf, nomeTitular, saldo):
        Self.numero = numero
        Self.cpf = cpf
        Self.nomeTitular = nomeTitular
        Self.saldo = saldo

    def depositar(self, valor):
        self.valor += valor

    def sacar(self, valor):
        self.saldo -= valor

    def gerarExtrato(self):
        print(f"Numero{self.numero} \n Cpf: {self.cpf} \n Saldo: {self.saldo}")

    def sacar(self,valor):
        if self.saldo < valor:
            return False
        else:
            self.saldo -= valor
            return True
```

Comment: Verifiquei aqui e está sim :/

Comment: está exatamente como na resposta que vc colocou.

Comment: Pra mim aqui a saída está normal. Executando o ClassA.py, tenho este resultado:

Numero3 
 Cpf: 456
 Saldo: 0

Comment: será que pode ser algum bug do VScode ?

Comment: Eu executei no VS Code mesmo. Com os dois códigos no mesmo diretório, rodam perfeitamente, sem erro algum.